# SSH allows publickey and password, but never asks for password, even if publickey fails

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I am using a 1and1 host and connecting from my Ubuntu 16.04 desktop.  I previously set up public key ssh access to my server, but haven't used it for about a year and something on the server end seems to have changed, making it so that it no longer works.

I never disabled password access, but I'm not promped for a password, even after the publickey authentication fails.  Here's the output.  Any help would be much appreciated!

```
<local_user>@computer01:~$ ssh -v <remote_user>@<server>.com
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/<local_user>/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/<local_user>/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for <server>.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to <server>.com [<server_ip>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/<local_user>/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<local_user>/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<local_user>/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<local_user>/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<local_user>/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<local_user>/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<local_user>/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<local_user>/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u1~ui80+7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u1~ui80+7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to <server>.com:22 as '<remote_user>'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: <server_host_key>
debug1: Host '<server>.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/<local_user>/.ssh/known_hosts:16
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key <local_user>@computer01 - not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes
debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key <local_user>@computer01 - not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/<local_user>/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: <local_user>@computer01
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/<local_user>/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/<local_user>/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/<local_user>/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
<local_user>@computer01:~$
```

Comment: `ssh -vvv -oPreferredAuthentications=password <remote_user>@<server>.com`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by editing my local /etc/ssh/ssh_config file.  I thought that this file configured *incoming* connections, but it turns out it configures *all* connections.

I commented out *PasswordAuthentication no* and was able to log in to my remote server.